# Не понимаю работу деструктора для графа, который задается массивом указателей на списки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, графы

Снизу класс Grl для графа, функция добавление ребра и сам деструктор. Не понимаю как там указатель E[j] может стать nullptr? Ведь по логике, первая структура будет указывать на следующую и так далее, а последняя на первую, либо я не так понимаю это.

```
class GrL : public GrA {
public:
    ~GrL();
    bool create(uint n);
    bool addArc(uint, uint);
    VList neighbors(uint v);
protected:
    typedef struct Node { uint v; Node* next; } *PNode, **PPNode;
    PPNode E;
    void dfsr(uint start, VList & L, bool * & visited);
    void bfsc(uint start, VList & L, bool * & visited);
};
bool GrL::addArc(uint i, uint j)
{
    PNode p = new(nothrow) Node;
    if (p == nullptr)
        return false;
    p->v = j;
    p->next = E[i];
    E[i] = p;
    if (!isDir)
    {
        PNode p = new(nothrow) Node;
        if (p == nullptr)
            return false;
        p->v = i;
        p->next = E[j];
        E[j] = p;
    }
    ++m;
    return true;
}
GrL::~GrL()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        PNode p;
        while (E[j] != nullptr)
        {
            p = E[j];
            E[j] = E[j] ->next;
            delete p;
        }
    }
    delete[]E;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что именно не понимаете?

Нарисуйте на бумаге ячейки массива, и из каждой вниз висит веревочка с бумажными флажками.

Встали в ячейку (внешний цикл), и пошли по веревочке вниз. Левой рукой берём флажок (p), правую по верёвочке переставляем на следующий (next), теперь левой обрываем флажок,  и повторяем, подтягивая левую к правой, пока веревочка не кончится (внутренний цикл while)

Когда веревочка кончилась, вырываем её из ячейки `delete[]E`

Comment: не понимаю как E[j] становится nullptr? я чуть выше кода написав это

Comment: А где сказано, что списки кольцевые? Изначально E[j] была нулевой, потом в нее вставляют узел, вытягивая верёвочку вниз. Если порядок вставки был A, B, C, то E[j] содержит C, указывает на B, И указывает на A, А указывает на ноль

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, понял, что в начале *next установится на nullptr